# TypeError: unsupported types for : 'int', 'NoneType' in Python

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

I am writing a program for a client that receives a string of an average from a server through the built in radio of averages which the client records. I'm getting a TypeError saying: "unsupported types for : 'int', 'NoneType'".

Here is my code:

```
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.on()

blink = Image("99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999")


radio.send("power on")

while True:
   incoming = radio.receive()
   if incoming is not None:
      incoming = float(incoming)

   sleep(500 - running_time() % 500)
   acceleration = accelerometer.get_z()
   radio.send(str(acceleration))
   acceleration = float(acceleration)

   if acceleration > 2 * incoming or acceleration < .5 * incoming:
       display.show(blink)
       microbit.sleep(150)
       display.clear()
       microbit.sleep(150)
```

The error happens in this line:

```
if acceleration > 2 * incoming or acceleration < .5 * incoming:
```

Comment: I think you are missing an indentation (for the last `if`)...

Comment: `incoming` is holding `None` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.on()

blink = Image("99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999:"
              "99999")


radio.send("power on")

while True:
   incoming = radio.receive()
   if incoming is not None:
      incoming = float(incoming)

      sleep(500 - running_time() % 500)
      acceleration = accelerometer.get_z()
      radio.send(str(acceleration))
      acceleration = float(acceleration)

      if acceleration > 2 * incoming or acceleration < .5 * incoming:
          display.show(blink)
          microbit.sleep(150)
          display.clear()
          microbit.sleep(150)
```

**Rationale:** Your code (as posted) executes the first `if` to check whether `incoming` is `None`. However, then you have the following code blocks at a previous indentation level and thus, those blocks execute also when `incoming` is `None`.